# How do I list only new files via the Backblaze B2 API?

Tags: backblaze

According to the [b2_list_file_names documentation](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/docs/b2_list_file_names.html) "This call returns at most 1000 file names per transaction" and you can use the `nextFileName` field to get the next 1000 files, and so on. It doesn't say in which order these files are returned, but the [documentation for the similar b2_list_file_versions](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/docs/b2_list_file_versions.html) says "in alphabetical order by file name" so one might suspect it's the same for b2_list_file_names.

This would imply that any new files uploaded between calls to b2_list_file_names will not appear at the end of the list.

**Is it possible to either choose chronological order for b2_list_file_names or in any other way get the latest uploaded files?**

In order to avoid an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) situation, this is what I really want to do:

Set legal_hold to "on" for all files, and do it for all new files once a week. Since I have ~400k files it costs money (I think) to list all files every time.

So another way to solve my problem would be to list all files with legal_hold not set to "on". **Is that possible?**

Comment: Turns out I hadn't read the billing information correctly. Listing 400 000 files converts to 400 class C operations (assuming you specify 1000 files per request), and you get 2 500 class C operations for free each day. So no problem for me! I'll leave the question, though, since this could be a problem for someone else.

Comment: Hi @Peter - could you turn your comment into an answer so that people can more easily see the solution?

Comment: Actually I think my comment is not an answer to the question as I have stated it ("How do I list only new files via the Backblaze B2 API"). The comment is more along the lines of "I don't need to know the answer since I have few enough files right now that I can list all files without running into the limit".

Comment: Fair enough - I'll write an answer that addresses your original question. I didn't want to do so before asking.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this with B2 (or indeed S3) is to use the file name. A common approach is to use a date prefix, naming your files with a convention such as `yyyy-MM-dd/fileName`. You can then query for all the files for a given day using the prefix parameter.

Since you're working on a weekly basis, you can optimize this by using `yyyy-ww/fileName` where `ww` is the week in the year.

If, on the other hand, you wanted a chronological ordering, you could use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss/fileName` and then use the `startFileName` parameter to get all files since a given point in time.